# SVG pixelation in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, svg

This is very strange. I am using SVG images, because of the low file size, sharp rendering, and scalability ( the objects animate quite a bit ). Its working perfect in FF, ie9, Safari and iPad, but in chrome certain SVG images are rendering very poorly.

[image: SVG in chrome]

[image: SVG in safari]

Any ideas why this might be happening? The svg files themselves are very small.

Here is some a sample svg

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should probably file a bugreport on Chrome, and it would be easier to answer if you had some example code in the question :)

Comment: I added a better live sample.

Comment: I've filed a bugreport: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119471 Waiting for an answer...

Comment: I've filed a another bug, CSS-free, SVG is pixelated on chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849679

Comment: I has happened to me when working on a CSS animation with both moving and blinking elements. There was one step in which the SVG was sharp, and the other was blurry, pixelated (in Firefox it was always pixelated, and even more that in Chrome).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So anyway, this is a legit chrome bug. And there is a fix, make the svg 'larger', svg files that internally report as too small cause this bug.

Comment: Some people can't handle the truth! hahah

Comment: Bigger in what sence @Fresheyeball? Filesize? Or css dimensions?

Comment: I'll upvote to counter the downvote, this answers the question. :)

Comment: 5 years later and I'm having this problem, but under a complex series circumstances which involve me (stupidly, yes!) using Chrome to print a 300dpi publication going through a formal print process. 

Pretty sure my heavy use of the `zoom` property is causing this to flare up in a way that Chrome hasn't accounted for. 

Sorry, the point I want to make is that regardless of the SVG's size, this issue persisted until I tried the lower-voted answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562330/svg-pixelation-in-chrome#answer-31072891

Answer (score 9):

After many researches, I finally found a working fix:
export the svg twice the needed dimensions (I therefore named it filename@2x.svg)
then in css, add `transform: scale(0.5)`

The result in Chrome will look the same as in Firefox.

Comment: Scouring dozens of issues on StackOverflow and reading about this everywhere, I found this was the only workaround to trick Chrome into rendering the SVGs properly in the PDF I'm printing. My situation was also VERY complex and involved, multiple layers of the `zoom` and `scale` properties.

Comment: This perhaps used to work back in 2015 but not anymore

Answer (score 3):

None of the workarounds (`opacity: 0.99`, `transform: scale(0.5)`, …) worked for me, so I went with this instead:

**PNG@2x** (twice the size PNG)

I simply removed SVGs and went with PNGs instead. To make sure they look nice even on Retina and other high resolution displays I exported them twice the size as actually needed.

This works well in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks. In my case x4 fixed the quality issue. Doesn't hurt because it's a small logo.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you did and how you did it? Like how some other answers have CSS or whatever code snippets? I'm not exactly sure what you mean with PNG@2x.

Comment: @TheTruth I removed SVGs and went with PNGs instead. To make sure they look nice even on Retina and other high resolution displays I would always export them twice the size as actually needed.

Comment: @BugsBunny ah I see. Not something I can do unfortunately. I have a dynamic changeable inline SVG text situation and I just can't use anything but that. Can't pre make a PNG for every possible text combo. Thanks for the answer still!

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this bug too with an element wit an SVG background. The workaround was to reduce the opacity by .01, i.e.:

```
.thing {
    background: url('my-image.svg');
    opacity: 0.99;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I could even reduce only by 0.0001.

Comment: Perfectly! You save my life. Thank you!

Comment: This does not work at all...

Comment: Wasted time. Does not work.

Comment: @mjs testing is never a waste.

Comment: Decreasing opacity works in 2023