# Using SVG as CSS3 background-image with scaling

Tags: html, css, svg

When I use SVG in background property like this:

```
.svg-button {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3.0) // root of the problem!
    background: url(Button.svg) no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

I get blurred image as result. At the same time text in tag with this style is clear. Also if I scale page by using CTRL++ (browser zoom) instead transform property everything is clear.

If I replace CSS background property on:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="Button.svg" width="32" height="32"></object>
```

the image is clear in any scale in any case.

Where is the problem?

**Sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Re6Cf/)**

**Update:**
I found some more information about this problem:

1. [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562330/svg-pixelation-in-chrome)
2. [Bug ticket for Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119471) (I tried my test under Safari/Chrome/IE9/10 and behaviour is the same.

Comment: SVG backgrounds as CSS backgrounds are sadly only supported by Opera and Webkit-browsers. Have you tried `background-size: 300%;` instead of transforming the background?

Comment: This is just sample. In real case I apply transformation for the root of the hierarchy.

Comment: It would help if you posted a jsfiddle with the requisite files so that people could actually see exactly what is/is not working, and "fiddle" with it.

Comment: @feeela all recent browsers support SVG as CSS backgrounds, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Chrome/Safari IE9/10 I have decided to use CSS zoom property instead scale property.

```
.svg-button {
    zoom: 300%;
    background: url(Button.svg) no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

For Firefox I still use CSS scale property because Firefox doesn't support zoom property. At the same time Firefox scales SVG background well. [See result](http://jsfiddle.net/5N8mq/).

For IE9 I have written javascript which temporary modifies CSS width property and after small delay returns it back. In this way I force redraw CSS background.

Answer (score 0):

I was "playing" with this a while back and noticed this for fonts too. Although it seems to be fixed now (for the fonts at least).

As far as I understand the inner workings, the contents of the scaled element are mapped to a texture, which in turn is scaled.

As a workaround, try using a 3d translation and move the element on the z-axis to achieve the size change. This won't yield as much control over the final outcome though.

```
.svg-button {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) translateZ(-300px);
    background: url(Button.svg) no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for. Interesting workarround, but I think it is not well suited for real application. I would like to understand the nature of my problem.