# Blurry emoji in canvas with chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

In chrome if I insert a emoji with a very large font, it appears blurry. This does not happen in firefox.

Is it a bug or is there a canvas setting I'm missing?

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "530px Arial";
ctx.fillText("", 0, 500);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1400" height="700"></canvas>
```

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]
[image: Chrome detail]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]
[image: Firefox detail]

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [svg-pixelation-in-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562330/svg-pixelation-in-chrome)