# Complex SVG is pixelated in Chrome but renders correctly in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, svg, firefox

I am working on a project in Next JS that uses some complex SVGs as background elements. Here is a sample of what the background looks like in Chrome vs Firefox:

Chrome:

[image: Chrome render]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox render]

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562330/svg-pixelation-in-chrome) from 11 years ago, but none of the suggestions (opacity: 0.99, transform: scale(0.5)) worked for me, so I'm leaning towards converting to PNG, however I wanted to check here first in case anyone has any ideas. How can I get the SVG to render crisply in Chrome as it does in Firefox?

Here is a snippet of the issue:

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <style>

   .geo-100 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Geo_Halftone.svg')
   }

   .geo-500 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 500px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Geo_Halftone.svg')
   }

   .geo-5000 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 5000px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Geo_Halftone.svg')
   }

   .geo-uneven-100 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Geo_Halftone_Uneven.svg')
   }

   .geo-uneven-500 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 500px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Geo_Halftone_Uneven.svg')
   }

   .geo-uneven-5000 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 5000px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Geo_Halftone_Uneven.svg')
   }

   .triangles-100 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Triangles_Halftone.svg')
   }

   .triangles-500 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 500px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Triangles_Halftone.svg')
   }

   .triangles-5000 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 5000px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_Triangles_Halftone.svg')
   }

   .specks-100 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg')
   }

   .specks-500 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 500px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg')
   }

   .specks-5000 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 5000px;
     background-image: url('https://momentarium.com/SVG-test/BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg')
   }
   
   
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>BgTile_Geo_Halftone.svg, height: 100px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="geo-100">   
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_Geo_Halftone.svg, height: 500px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="geo-500">   
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_Geo_Halftone.svg, height: 5000px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="geo-5000">   
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_Geo_Halftone_Uneven.svg, height: 100px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="geo-uneven-100">   
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_Geo_Halftone_Uneven.svg, height: 500px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="geo-uneven-500">   
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_Geo_Halftone_Uneven.svg, height: 5000px (aliased in Chrome, not aliased in Firefox):</h1>
  <div class="geo-uneven-5000">
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_Triangles_Halftone.svg, height: 100px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="triangles-100">
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_Triangles_Halftone.svg, height: 500px (aliased in Chrome, not aliased in Firefox):</h1>
  <div class="triangles-500">
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_Triangles_Halftone.svg, height: 5000px (aliased in Chrome, not aliased in Firefox):</h1>
  <div class="triangles-5000">
  </div>
  
  <h1>BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg, height: 100px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="specks-100">
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg, height: 500px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="specks-500">
  </div>

  <h1>BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg, height: 5000px (not aliased):</h1>
  <div class="specks-5000">
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

I tested the 4 SVGs as backgrounds in divs of 3 heights: 100px, 500px, and 5000px. I did this because I noticed different results when the height of the div changed. Here are my results in Chrome:

BgTile_Geo_Halftone.svg

- 100px: crisp
- 500px: crisp
- 5000px: crisp

BgTile_Geo_Halftone_Uneven.svg

- 100px: crisp
- 500px: crisp
- 5000px: aliased

BgTile_Triangles_Halftone.svg

- 100px: crisp
- 500px: aliased
- 5000px: aliased

BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg

- 100px: crisp
- 500px: crisp
- 5000px: crisp

Some observations:

- When I adjust the height of the 5000px high BgTile_Geo_Halftone_Uneven.svg, it becomes  crisp below 2649px high.
- When I adjust the height of the 100px high BgTile_Triangles_Halftone.svg, it turns from crisp to aliased at 321px high.
- BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg is crisp in all cases, possibly due to a smaller file size?
- All cases are crisp in Firefox

Edit: It has come to my attention that the height points where the aliasing happens aligns with the height of the SVGs. After some testing, it seems that anything that causes repeat-y of the SVG background (either height of the container > height of the SVG, or background-position on the y axis) will become aliased in Chrome. It happens with the first 3 SVGs in the snippet, however it does not happen with other SVGs on my site, which are much smaller in size (example: BgTile_DarkSpecks_Invert.svg). Maybe it only happens in Chrome with larger SVGs that exceed a certain file size or dimension?

Comment: Maybe include the SVG... You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a link to Codepen with the SVGs and test code.

Comment: That is not an SO snippet

Comment: Apologies, I confused code sample with snippet. It is now a snippet.

Comment: Dear god... the first svg i checked out was over 4MB. My design software slows to a crawl trying to display the gazillions of vertices in vertex-editing mode. I don't know exactly what's happening w the rendering but I wonder if certain browsers automatically are rasterizing vector backgrounds over a certain file size? A multi-Mb vector is A LOT for a browser to chew through just to show a simple background. A literally identical image could be made in <100 kB using an svg path as a clipping/masking boundary for that repeating background of dots (which could be defined entirely in css)

Comment: I totally agree with @diopside – your svgs are way to large. Loading these files already takes ages. Most svg optimizers (e.g SVGOMG) will also fail to significantly reduce the file size due to the complexity. Even a high-res raster image will perform better and quite likely also provide a  smaller file size.  To some extent you might use the svg `<pattern>`  element to display a tiled halftone raster and apply a `<clipPath>` – webkit browsers like safari also tend to render them only once (so it becomes blurry when zooming in)